# What are possible STATUS of docker nodes?

Tags: docker

when running `docker node ls`, there is a STATUS field. 
What are possible node status other than ready? 
and where is this information written? shouldn't it be provided with its documentation here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_ls/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the possible statuses from the [node type](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/api/types/swarm/node.go):

```
const (
    NodeStateUnknown NodeState = "unknown"
    NodeStateDown NodeState = "down"
    NodeStateReady NodeState = "ready"
    NodeStateDisconnected NodeState = "disconnected"
)
```

You typically only see `ready` and `down` (even if you do `swarm leave` on a node, it shows as `down`), so I'm not sure what triggers `disconnected`.

And yes this should be in the docs - they're linked to GitHub so you can [edit](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/edit/master/engine/reference/commandline/node_ls.md) that page or [submit an issue](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/new?title=Feedback%20for:%20engine/reference/commandline/node_ls.md&body=URL:%20[https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_ls.md](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_ls/)).

Answer (score 1):

They are: `Unknown`, `Down`, `Ready`, `Disconnected`.

See [docker/swarm - node.go](https://github.com/docker/swarm/blob/439031691c38c0904c6f833cbb583c330e201705/vendor/github.com/docker/engine-api/types/swarm/node.go#L107)